# Clarification: Is it true trace of $(A^TA)$ is induced matrix norm squared?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be an n x n matrix, where the trace is the sum of the diagonal elements. Show that $tr(A^{T}A)$=$\|A\|_2^2$.

Question/Concerns: I was given this question.  However, I'm concerned about what norm they are talking about in the question.  Is it the induced Matrix 2-norm squared? Or do you think that it is the Frobenius Norm squared?
I know that:$\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=\|A\|_2^2$ where this notation represents the induced Matrix 2-norm squared.  However, it is not always true that the trace of $A^TA$ is equal to the maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$.
Example:(Taken from another stack exchange post):
Consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \ \  0 \\ 0 \ \ \frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$Then $$\hbox{tr}(A^TA) = \hbox{tr}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{4} \ \  0 \\ 0 \ \ \frac{1}{9}\end{pmatrix} = \frac{13}{36} < \frac{1}{4} = \lambda_{max} \ \mbox {greatest eigenvalue of $A^{T}$*A}$$.

Thus, they must be talking about the Frobenius Norm? I'm just confused because the Frobenius Norm is typically denoted: $\|A\|_F$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Compute the diagonal elements of $A^TA$, then the trace: the trace is the sum of squares of elements of the matrix, hence the square of the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut So they are talking about Frobenius Norm not induced matrix 2 norm? Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Since you already proved it's not the square of the $2$-norm, and I told you how to prove it's the square of Frobenius norm, there is not much left to clarify.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you I know how to prove it is the square of the Frobenius Norm. It's just weird as I believe the notation used in the problem is not standard.

Comment: Sometimes the matrix norm induced by the vector norm $||v||_p$ is noted $|||A|||_p$. I don't know if it's a standard notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (A^T A)_{kl} = \sum_{r}a^T_{rl} a_{kr}  = \sum_{r}a_{lr} a_{kr} $$
so, taking the trace
$$trace(A^T A) == \sum_{k} (A^T A)_{kk} =\sum_{kr}a_{kr} a_{kr} $$

The formula should tell you which norm (squared) this is.